# Invalid working of #springFormSingleSelect in velocity template

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, velocity

I am making spring mvc application and using velocity templates for views.There is form for filling it by the data and in this form i am using #springFormSingleSelect.Form  works fine when data is valid, but when form is filled by invalid data as mentioned there are messages with errors, but #springFormSingleSelect is empty.That's my view:

```
<form action="saveEmployee" method="POST">
                #springBind("newEmployee")
            <a href="listEmployees">#springMessage("label.back")</a>
            <p>
            <table>                
                <tr>
                    <td>#springMessage("label.firstName")</td>
                    <td>#springFormInput("newEmployee.firstName" "")</td>
                    <td><font color="red">#springShowErrors("&nbsp" "")</font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>#springMessage("label.lastName")</td>
                    <td>#springFormInput("newEmployee.lastName" "")</td>
                    <td><font color="red">#springShowErrors("&nbsp" "")</font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>#springMessage("label.salary")</td>
                    <td>#springFormInput("newEmployee.salary" "")</td>
                    <td><font color="red">#springShowErrors("&nbsp" "")</font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>#springMessage("label.birthdate")</td>
                    <td>#springFormInput("newEmployee.birthday" "")</td>
                    <td><font color="red">#springShowErrors("&nbsp" "")</font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>#springMessage("label.departament")</td>
                    <td>#springFormSingleSelect("newEmployee.departamentId" $departamentsMap "")</td>
               </tr>

            </table>
                    <input type="submit" value="#springMessage("label.submit")">
        </form>
```

That's part of controller to the view:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveEmployee", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newuserForm(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("newEmployee");
        Employee empl = new Employee();

        Map departamentsMap = new TreeMap();
        List<Departament> departamentsList = service.listDepartaments();

        //for singleselect of departaments
        for(int i=0; i<departamentsList.size(); i++){
            Departament dep = departamentsList.get(i);
            departamentsMap.put(dep.getDepartamentId(),dep.getTitle() );
        }                    
        model.addObject("departamentsMap",departamentsMap);

        model.getModelMap().put("newEmployee", empl);
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/saveEmployee", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String create(@ModelAttribute("newEmployee")Employee empl, BindingResult result){

        employeeValidator.validate(empl, result);
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "newEmployee";
        }
        service.saveEmployee(empl);
        return "redirect:/listEmployees";
    }
```

Maybe someone knows the reason of that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

departamentsMap is null at the time of Error...So please add model.addObject("departamentsMap",departamentsMap);
in your post detail ,So when eeror Occured it must not be null.

```
//Modified this line of code..


if(result.hasErrors()){
        Map departamentsMap = new TreeMap();
        List<Departament> departamentsList = service.listDepartaments();

        //for singleselect of departaments
        for(int i=0; i<departamentsList.size(); i++){
            Departament dep = departamentsList.get(i);
            departamentsMap.put(dep.getDepartamentId(),dep.getTitle() );
        }                    
        model.addObject("departamentsMap",departamentsMap);


   return "newEmployee";
        }
```